# Find specific string in subdirectories and order top directories by modification date

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a directory structure containing some files. I'm trying to find the names of top directories that do contain a file with specific string in it.

I've got this:

```
grep -r abcdefg . | grep commit_id | sed -r 's/\.\/(.+)\/.*/\1/';
```

Which returns something like:

```
topDir1
topDir2
topDir3
```

I would like to be able to take this output and somehow feed it into this command:

```
ls -t | grep -e topDir1 -e topDir2 -e topDir3
```

which would returned the output filtered by the first command and ordered by modification date.

I'm hoping for a one liner. Or maybe there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Since you mention commit ids, it seems like it is git related. Can you explain in plain English what do you really want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as long as none of the directory names contain whitespace or wildcard characters:

```
ls -td $(grep -r abcdefg . | grep commit_id | dirname)
```

Comment: Your solution of ls -td $(...) solves my problem. The "dirname" part does not do what I wanted, but after replacing dirname with sed, everything falls back into place.

Comment: Isn't your `sed` command just getting the directory part of the filenames?